# Creating classes dynamically in matlab

Tags: oop, matlab

Given a structure, is there a way to create a class in MATLAB? Take for instance

```
>> p = struct(); p.x = 0; p.y = 0;
>> p

p = 

    x: 0
    y: 0

>> name = 'Point'

name =

Point
```

What I would like to do, is given a string containing the name of the class and a struct with containing the fields I would like to create a class without having to write a file explicitly writing the definition.

Right now if we use `class(p)` we will obtain `struct`. What I want to do is create an object of the type `Point` so that when I do `class(obj)` then I get `Point`.

Any ideas how to accomplish this besides writing a file in MATLAB with the class definition and then executing it?

Comment: What do you need dynamically created classes for?

Comment: @Jonas, I have a binary file with information about structures and its information. The information includes the name of the class, the fields it contains and the datatype of the fields. I can read this information and store it in a simple struct in MATLAB, but I won't know the type of object that the struct is. I want to be able to construct this objects on the fly with the instructions of the binary file.

Comment: What about storing data in a struct-array with fields `Name` and `Data` where data is a struct with, like the name says, data.

Comment: @Mikhail, I thought about that but that would require the user to access an extra field: `p.Data.field1`. I think I'll just make MATLAB write a file with the class definition and then create an object of that type using `str2func` to get the handle of the newly created class constructor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Either you have specific functionality (methods) associated with the `Point` class as opposed to e.g. the `Line` class, in which case you should write out the classes by hand, anyway, or you can make a single `dynamicprops` class that can have dynamically created properties, and unless you really need to call a method named `class`, you much simplify your life by calling `classname` instead.

```
classdef myDynamicClass < dynamicprops
properties (Hidden)
myClass %# this stores the class name
end
methods
function obj = myDynamicClass(myClassName,varargin)
%# synopsis: obj = myDynamicClass(myClassName,propertyName,propertyValue,...)
%# myClassName is the name of the class that is returned by 'classname(obj)'
%# propertyName/propertyValue define the dynamic properties

obj.myClass = myClassName;

for i=1:2:length(varargin)
addprop(obj,varargin{i})
obj.(varargin{i}) = varargin{i+1};
end
end

function out = classname(obj)
out = obj.myClass;
end

end 
end
```

Comment: I sort of like this. If I call `class` an a `myDynamicClass` object I will obtain `myDynamicClass`. I can use this to then check for the real classname by using the function defined there. This will behave better than just a struct because it will check to see if it has the right fields. Thanks Jonas, now I won't have to write a different file for every class specified in the binary file.

Comment: @jmlopez: You're welcome. Note that you can also create set and get methods for the dynamic properties, so that you can add additional functionality for e.g. error checking.

Comment: back in '11 I should have said, "Oh really? How can I create the set and get methods for my dynamic properties?", After having a struggle thinking about how to do this I came up with [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20810965/788553). Is that the proper way to create the set methods?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of any way of creating objects dynamically, so I'd say the answer to your question is **no**. However, to solve your problem, I would propose something very similar to what Mikhail said:

Work with a struct with fields `x`, `y` and `classname`:

```
p.x=0;
p.y=0;
p.classname='Point';
```

and then write a function `myclass(x)` which returns `x.classname`. If for some reason you need to use `class()` you could even overload it with your own function which checks if `x` is one of your special structs and calls `builtin('class', x)` otherwise:

```
function out=class(varargin)
if nargin==1 && isstruct(varargin{1}) ... #check if we were given a struct
   && isfield(varargin{1}, 'classname') ... #...which contains a field classname
   && ischar(varargin{1}.classname) %# ... which is a string
    out=varargin{1}.classname; %# ok, our special case :-)
else
    out=builtin('class',varargin{:}); %# normal case - call builtin class()
end
```

Answer (score 1):

One solution that I've used in the past is to write a MATLAB function that takes this information (i.e. the class name and fields) and writes an M-file containing the required classdef construct.

This works well if you're using this information to describe a prototype that you want to expand later.